# Bootstrap 4 tooltip style only works in the first section

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have a table that at first only shows 10 rows and here the tooltip displays correctly [image: Tooltip 1st], but if I change to the next page or display more entries the tooltip doesn’t work correctly in the next ones [image: Tooltip 2nd].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok nvm I found the solution with the next part of code:

```
var table = $('#table').DataTable({

            drawCallback: function (settings) {
                var api = this.api();

                $('name', api.table().container()).tooltip({
                    container: 'body'
                });
            }  

        });
```

'name' is the id of your tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this bug before. Basically when you change the page it paints the thing again and you have to re-trigger the tooltip.

What you can do is add an event listener to the pageindex and run `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` everytime the pageindex changes.

Comment: I'm already using that and it loads at first once (every time you load the page) ... the problem is that when I change of page (in the table) or display more entries (of the table), I'm not reloading anything of the page, the data is already there.